# FileNotFoundException while calling RESTFul API using AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection, filenotfoundexception, android-studio-2.1

I am developing simple Login application. But I am stuck at the point where I get `FileNotFoundException` upon calling(or hitting) API using android `Asynctask`. Also the status code I got after calling is 400. But I don't get it where I went wrong.
Below is the code of calling API from doInBackground method of asynctask.

```
@Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedWriter writer = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try
        {
            String email = params[0];
            String password = params[1];


            URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.67:8080/eye/api/login");

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");


            List<NameValuePair> loginCredentials = new ArrayList<>();

            loginCredentials.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", email));
            loginCredentials.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

            out = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getQuery(loginCredentials));
            writer.flush();

            int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            if (statusCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                Log.d("LoginActivity", "Connection failed: StatusCode: " + statusCode);
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("LoginActivity", "Connection Success: StatusCode: " + statusCode);
            }

            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            responseText = getResponseText(in);
            return new JSONObject(responseText);
          }
            catch (Exception e)
          {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
           return null;
       }
```

P.S. :- getQuery() is the function that will append & encode URL Parameters.And 
        getResponseText() is the function that reads the response that have come from the server. Just FYI, the control of execution enters into catch block after the line  `InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());`

Also if I hit this particular URL via Postman, I get 200(HTTP OK) as a response code.

This is what error log states:

```
12-15 16:24:07.028  26145-26182/krixi.com.spanpumploginhit W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://192.168.1.67:8080/eye/api/login
12-15 16:24:07.029  26145-26182/krixi.com.spanpumploginhit W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:206)
12-15 16:24:07.029  26145-26182/krixi.com.spanpumploginhit W/System.err﹕ at krixi.com.spanpumploginhit.Login$AsyncCheckLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:213)
12-15 16:24:07.029  26145-26182/krixi.com.spanpumploginhit W/System.err﹕ at krixi.com.spanpumploginhit.Login$AsyncCheckLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:153)
12-15 16:24:07.029  26145-26182/krixi.com.spanpumploginhit W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
12-15 16:24:07.029  26145-26182/krixi.com.spanpumploginhit W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-15 16:24:07.029  26145-26182/krixi.com.spanpumploginhit W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
12-15 16:24:07.029  26145-26182/krixi.com.spanpumploginhit W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
12-15 16:24:07.029  26145-26182/krixi.com.spanpumploginhit W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
12-15 16:24:07.029  26145-26182/krixi.com.spanpumploginhit W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Thanks :-)

Comment: Post your error log.

Comment: @DevendraSingh posted...

Comment: First make sure the server is working correctly by using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com) or using **CURL**.

Answer (score 0):

if you are running on localhost, then use 10.0.2.2:[portNumber] in address.

Comment: urlConnection.connect(); to connect url connection.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer. If you are fed up of debugging above code, try using `HttpClient` instead of `HttpURLConnection`. It worked for me.
Just try below code, in your doInBackground().

```
        String email = params[0];
        String password = params[1];
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";

        try {
            // 1. create HttpClient

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // 2. make POST request to the given URL
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.67:8080/eye/api/login");

            String json = "";

            // 3. build jsonObject
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.accumulate("username", email);
            jsonObject.accumulate("password", password);

            // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
            json = jsonObject.toString();



            // 5. set json to StringEntity
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

            // 6. set httpPost Entity
            httpPost.setEntity(se);

            // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

            // 9. receive response as inputStream
            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

            // 10. convert inputstream to string
            if (inputStream != null)
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            else
                result = "Did not work!";


        }catch (Exception e){

        }
```

Don't forget to add below dependency in your app level build.gradle

```
compile group: 'cz.msebera.android' , name: 'httpclient', version: '4.4.1.1'
```

Let me know if it worked!

P.S. :- 
    convertInputStreamToString(inputStream) is the Helper method to convert inputstream to String

Thank you.